# Sencha TreePicker does not show scrollbar

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I am trying to run the code from this link - [Sencha TreePicker - Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8bh). I am unable to get the scrollbars to show-up. In the fiddle it shows up as expected since it uses EXTJS 5.0.

I am using EXTJS 6.0.2-Classic for my app. And this is what I am getting :
[image]

I tried setting these properties on the panel:

```
autoScroll: true
scroll: true
```

But it made no difference. Any suggestions to get the vertical and horizontal scrolls?

Comment: The [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8bh) works even with ExtJS 6.0.2 , you can switch the version of ExtJS there. So there must be something else wrong in your code. You can post your fiddle with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the fiddle is working because the parent component has set a height and a width and you did not do that.
You need to set this to get either of the scroller (height for vertical, width for horizontal scroller).

The easiest way to achieve is to set your component to

```
flex: 1
```